# Scanning data into mvc web application then changing focus

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I am writing a small database where I can scan multiple bar codes into different text boxes then save the data. The bar code data can have some variance in length and I would like to move focus to the next text box after the bar code is done scanning.

Here is the latest code in my view where I give each text box an id then I use jquery to focus on the next id after the first text box has reached a certain length.

```
<!--This is for entering the PartNumber-->
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartNum, 
       htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PartNum, 
       new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="focus1"} })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartNum, "", 
       new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

        <!--This is for entering the Aisle-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Aisle, 
               htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Aisle, 
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",id="focus2" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Aisle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$('input[id=focus').keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length == 2) {
            $('input[id=focus2]').focus();
        }
    });
```

From what I can tell from the code, this should move focus to the next textbox after 2 characters are entered/scanned into the first textbox, but this does not work.

I would then like to make the focus change after the barcode of variable length is done scanning but not sure how to do this.

What am I doing wrong in my code that will not let focus change to the next textbox?

Comment: Are you sure the scanner even triggers the `keyup` event?

Comment: I am not sure if it is or not. In another part of the application I scan the bar code into an @html.TextBox with an id then when after the keyup event and the length is 7 characters I have jquery click an input submit and the application will submit the data and load the next page. I know this is using click instead of focus but I think it would be the same concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the main issue I was having was I forgot to include 
  `$(function(){`
at the start of my code.
On to the main solution that I was able to work out.

```
$(function(){
    $('#focus1').keyup(function(){
        if(!_timeoutRunning){
            _timeoutRunning=true;
            setTimeout(function(){checkKey();}, 2000);
        }
    });
});

var _timeoutRunning = false;

function checkKey(){
    _timeoutRunning = false;
    if($('#focus1').val().length >= 7)
        $('#focus2').focus();
}
```

this code allows me to scan in a bar code that is of length 7 or more then 2 seconds after the 7th character is scanned in it will change focus to the next id

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You could try the following:

```
$('input[id*="focus"]').each(function () {
     if($(this).val().length >= 2) {
          $(this).next().focus();
     }
});
```

I'm not sure about your structure, but the jQuery is pretty straight forward.  Iterate through each element with the word `focus`, if the value is greater than two, move focus to the next element.  (May have to tweak next to hit proper element)

Also this will have some overhead, as a loop will occur with each iteration.

---

I'm not sure if the `keyup` Event would actually be triggered. Also, your making sure it is equal to two, not equal or greater.  You could do the following though:

```
$('input[id=focus]).change(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     if($(this).val().length >= 2) {
          $('input[id=focus2]').focus();
     }
});
```

You may also want to scale this code, where it auto increments to the next available `id` for focus.

Comment: I am not sure either if the keyup is being triggered. I am using similar syntax elsewhere in my project where using jquery I click the submit button after a certain number of characters are entered into a textbox. Is there a way I can change my code to trigger the keyup Event? @Greg

Comment: Not sure, that is why I recommended `change`.  Because if you do: `$('...').val('Example');` that wouldn't trigger a `keyup`.

Comment: I missed the change part the first time I ran it. But after I fixed that I still got the same result as before (the focus does not change to the next text box). When I change the "@Html.TextBoxFor( model =>model.PartNum...)" into "@Html.TextBox("PartNum"...)" and use  my original script, I am able to change the focus, but this would require changing how I deal with my data in my controller.

Comment: Hm, I've got an idea but not sure how I could have you implement easily.

Comment: @vanderpm I thought of an idea, not sure of your exact usage so it may not be ideal but it may be a solid work around otherwise.

Comment: After the data is in the text boxes, I just submit it into a one table database.  The main goal is to be able to scan a barcode in for the part number then the aisle without having to select the text box or hit tab to move to the next box.